# toggle tr if attr is ^=X and X.length + 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need help with javascript condition. I'd like upon click to toggle a table row (tr) and subsequent (tr) where conditions are met.

I have the code working thus far but am not sure how to add in this additional condition. This additional condition is if sortString is X characters long, and subsequent tr have a sortString which are X+1, X+2, X+3, etc characters long to only toggle sortString.length + 1. I.E. only toggle length 4 if length 3 was clicked, and not toggle anything greater than length 4 (in this example).

```
$('tr').click(function () {
    var sortString = $(this).closest('tr').attr('sort'); // works
    $('tr[sort=' + sortString + ']').toggle(); // works
    $('tr[sort^=' + sortString + ']').toggle(); // needs additional condition
}
```

My sortString has characters concatenated onto it. So it looks like 12, or 123, or 1234, or 12345, etc. So if I clicked on a tr with a sortString of 123, then only tr with 1234 are toggled, and not 12345 (etc.)

I am guessing something like this...

```
$('tr[sort^=' + sortString + ']').(sortString.length + 1).toggle();
```

Comment: Please add plunker/fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to iterate your second selection so you can filter by an extra `if` statement.

```
$('tr[sort^=' + sortString + ']').each() {
    if ($(this).attr('sort').length == sortString.length + 1) {
        $(this).toggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was what I needed to do!.